# How change auto increment statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I create a table:

```
create table empty 
(
    data_id int identity(70,30),
    emp_name varchar(20),
    address varchar(20),
    city varchar(20)
)
```

and insert data like:

```
data_id   emp_name      address        city 
---------------------------------------------
70        ritesh        210 b_block     sivapur
100       pritma        visvaas khand   lucknow
130       rakesh        nehru nagar     delhi
```

Now I want to alter auto increment from `(70, 30)` to `(70, 10)`.

Can I do this?

Comment: The use of `identity` suggests that you are using SQL Server and not MySQL, so I removed the tag for the latter.

Comment: rename the existing table. create a new table with the same name as the old with the new seed. insert data from old table into new using the SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON so that existing keys are retained.

Comment: Once a column is defined as `IDENTITY`, you cannot modify it. Neither can you add the `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column (or remove it from a column).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a new column called `data_id_New`.

```
ALTER TABLE empty ADD data_id_New int;
```

Now copy all values of `data_id` into `data_id_New`.

```
Update empty set data_id_New = data_id
```

Now delete column.

```
ALTER TABLE empty DROP COLUMN data_id;
```

Rename column `data_id_New` to `data_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE empty RENAME COLUMN data_id_new to data_id;
```

Finally modify your new column

```
ALTER TABLE empty MODIFY data_id int identity(70,10);
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: You **cannot** (in SQL Server) use `ALTER TABLE .. MODIFY` - the command is `ALTER TABLE .... ALTER COLUMN ` but even with the correct syntax, you **CANNOT** add the `IDENTITY` specification to an existing column - just cannot be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can not change that in one go, you would need to create a new table and copy over the rows.

Try this to create a temp table, move over the rows, drop the old table and rename the temp table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_empty
    (
    data_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (70, 10),
    emp_name varchar(20) NULL,
    address varchar(20) NULL,
    city varchar(20) NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_empty ON
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.empty)
     EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_empty (data_id, emp_name, address, city)
        SELECT data_id, emp_name, address, city FROM dbo.empty WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_empty OFF
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.empty
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_empty', N'empty', 'OBJECT' 
GO
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DBCC CHECKIDENT`

```
  DBCC CHECKIDENT 
 ( 
   table_name
    [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ] } } ]
 )
  [ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Eg `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('empty', RESEED, 10);`

Please refer this [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx)

Comment: That doesn't change the increment, that resets the seed